# how to use prepared statement in following case?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I have following database schema for tabel tblpers

```
Field      Type         Null    Key     Default              Extra           Privileges                 

userid     int(11)      NO      PRI     (NULL)               auto_increment  
firstname  char(10)     NO                                
lastname   char(15)     NO              192.168.1.15
sdate  datetime     NO              0000-00-00 00:00:00
address    varchar(100) YES             (NULL)
```

Here is my java code;

```
public class PSMTTest {

private static String jdbcDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
private static String host="localhost";
private static String userName = "root"; 
private static String password = "rootpass";

public static void main(String args[]){

    Connection con=null;
    try{
        if(jdbcDriver!=null){
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/mysql";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);

            String insertQuery="insert into `querytest`.`tblpers` " +
            "(`userid`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`sdate`,`address`)values ( NULL,?,?,Now(),NULL);";

            System.out.println("insertQuery : "+insertQuery);

            PreparedStatement psmt=con.prepareStatement(insertQuery);

            psmt.setString(2,"param");
            psmt.setString(3,"ganak");  //as per the sql exception error comes here
            psmt.executeUpdate();
            psmt.close();

        }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But when I am tries to run the code It throws following exception

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2474)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:3191)
    at PSMTTest.main(PSMTTest.java:45)

My userid is a primary key and auto increment field so value for it is automatically generated by database.
for the fields firstname and lastname I have the values.
but in case of date I want to add current data and time of the db.

In case of address the value is not provided yet so it should be kept as it is

Please tell me friends whats wrong with the query in my code?
why its giving an exception?
please guide me friends!
Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory - you've only specified two parameter placeholders (question marks) but you're trying to use indexes 2 and 3. So this:

```
psmt.setString(2, "param");
psmt.setString(3, "ganak");
```

should be:

```
psmt.setString(1, "param");
psmt.setString(2, "ganak");
```

The fact that they are the second and third fields within the value list is irrelevant - they're the first and second *parameters*.

You could make the correspondence clearer by reordering your SQL though:

```
String insertQuery = "insert into `querytest`.`tblpers` " +
    "(`firstname`, `lastname`, `sdate`, `userid`, `address`) values " + 
    "(?, ?, Now(), NULL, NULL);";
```

Now the first and second prepared statement parameters correspond with the first and second fields specified in the SQL.

It's not clear to me that you *need* to specify the `userid` field anyway, mind you - given that it's going to be provided by default. I would remove it from the SQL entirely, to be honest.

Comment: Hello Sir! its good to see your reply again. Your solution works. you means to say that the index in psmt.setString() depends on the numnber of question mark and not on their place in the query. am I right?

Comment: @Param-Ganak: You need to differentiate between the parameters which the PreparedStatement understands (just the question marks) and the arguments for the SQL statement itself (which includes your NULL, NOW() etc). The index you use for `setString(...)` is *just* in terms of question marks: `setString(1, "x")` will effectively replace the first question mark with "x" etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and answer its cleared my doubt. Thank You once again!